# Security warning of the nodemon.ps1 file in the nodemon package

Tags: node.js, powershell, security, nodemon

What exactly does the `nodemon.ps1` file in the **nodemon** package do that causes a security warning and does not work? But why does the package work properly by deleting this file?

By deleting this file, the problem of the package not working was solved, but was the problem with the `nodemon.ps1` file?

Comment: (Unfortunately), PowerShell defaults to _preventing_ execution of script files (`*.ps1`) in workstation editions of Windows, necessitating a change in [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) to allow their execution. See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: Presumably, the reason that the package still works is that npm packages also come with batch files, which aren't subject to PowerShell's execution policy and therefore always executed.